# How to run MYSQL in MINGW64 on Windows10?

Tags: mysql, mingw-w64

I really liked the environment of MINGW64 on Windows10 since Python, TMUX and VIM come in handy through Pacman.  However,  there's no MYSQL package available for MINGW64.  How could I run/install MYSQL in MINGW64 on Windows10?

Comment: Does it have MariaDB package?

Comment: The package I found available in https://packages.msys2.org is the
mingw-w64-libmariadbclient(MariaDB client libraries (mingw-w64))

Comment: So... could it work for you if you're using MariaDB instead? I mean, because it's basically the same thing. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Thank you I will try it! I'm not familiar with MariaDB but I think it's worth a try and learn. thanks

Comment: Actually MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. The lead developer is one of MySQL founders. It has high compatibility with MySQL so almost everything that you can do in MySQL, you can do it in MariaDB as well.

Comment: I could not install using pacman the  mingw-w64-libmariadbclient.  I think it needs to be build, which I still need to study.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/Building_MariaDB_on_Windows/

Comment: @tcadidot0 I've followed the generic build instruction but It was not successful.  I found a little trick and it was working so far...

Answer (score 2):

I found a little trick since I was not successful in building the package for MingW64.
I downloaded the mariadb-10.4.11-winx64.msi from the mariadb download site and install the usual way. Added the MariaDB in the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:''C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\bin'
```

Install winpty using pacman:

```
pacman -Syu winpty
```

Enter **winpty mysql -u root -p**:

[image: MariaDB on MingW64]

Comment: Thank you! See, MariaDB is a branch of MySQL, which should be compatible for conventional engines
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB, there is also a 
SSL support https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/ and 
java binding https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/18919/) very recent pull request

you can just do (in mingw enviroment)

```
pacman -S ${MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX}-python-mysqlclient
```

Feel free to test in python

```
import MySQLdb

def test_connection():
    try:
        # Establish the connection
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host="mysql-rfam-public.ebi.ac.uk",
            user="rfamro",
            passwd="",
            port=4497,
            db="Rfam"
        )
        
        # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        # Execute a simple SQL query (for example, fetching version information)
        cursor.execute("SELECT DATABASE();")
        
        # Fetch the result
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(f"Connected to database: {result[0]}")
        
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        
    finally:
        # Close the cursor and connection
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_connection()
```

This uses a public MySql server